# Show if R is simple. then f is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings and $f : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism.
Show that if R is simple then either $f$ is injective or that $f(a) = 0$ for every $a \in R$.

I have that since $R$ is a simple ring, then we must have that the two sided ideals of $R$ are either $\{0\}$ and $R$. If we consider the ideal $I = \{x \in R | f(x) = 0\}$, since $f$ is a ring homomorphism, then $I$ is a two sided ideal of $R$ or $\{0\}$. Then if $I$ is $R$, $f(a)=0 \; \forall \; a \in R$. Also, $I = \{0\}$ where the kernel of the homomorphism is $0$ $\implies f$ is injective.

I was wondering if my proof is sufficient.All help is appreciated!

Comment: Your instructor is the ultimate authority, but this looks valid to me.

Comment: I find the proof almost sufficient, but not sufficiently clear and focused. The ideal $I$ is called the kernel of $f$. This is added a bit unconnected in your last sentence, which is not clear enough.

Comment: (1) You might want to ask whether the Proof is Correct & that can be Discussed Objectively. (2) Asking whether it is sufficient is Subjective , not Objective.